# Why settings of ubuntu was not restored like before?

Tags: clone

So, there is the question: I have done an clone of the root when I considered all things work fine (samba settings was done and sharing working like a charm). Then I tried other settings and things go wrong. I decided now is time to restore, so the restore of the root was done. When i have restarted system my first concern was file sharing which SURPRISE Not working, Nautilius see workgroup but folder is empty.**Why Nautilius was not restored like before?** Mention: Samba working because i can see files with direct connection with Nautilius from the bottom of his window. More, the adress of the computer was saved somehow because when i wrote **smb** in adress bar the whole adress popped. If someone know, please help.

Comment: This is unclear, you might want to check your question.  'cone of the root' means?  if you mean 'clone of the root' please be specific on what that means too, as little is usually found in /root/ ; and if you mean "/" that may not capture anything anyway and usually partitions/drives themselves are cloned. You also didn't provide anything on-topic, no OS/release details were provided (are you talking about a desktop, server, IoT appliance, or what?)

Comment: So i talking about two desktops, one with Ubuntu and one with Windows, but the real question is about Nautilius. Where Nautilius has saved adress of the other computer and why Nautilius didn`t come back just as I saved him?

Comment: The clone was made with Clonezilla and only the Root was saved.

Comment: I solved problem, I found here:  /home/<user>/.config/gtk-3.0 a file named <servers> and i opened this file with text editor. I have deleted all addresses of servers founded there then i have saved modifications. That was it, all shares become browsable from NAUTILIUS directly.

Comment: Whilst I didn't *fully* understand your issue, you solved it, so please write an answer. You can't accept it straight away (a chance for others to write a better answer), you'll be able to accept it in time.